# Image downloads using CURL and Linux, maximizing performance?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm downloading a large amount of images (.jpg) from various domains and I need to complete this in the fastest time possible. To perform this I'm using CURL along with concurreny threading with `std::async`, from my linux server (2 CPU, 40GB SSD)

However, I'm aware, that even with threading, my download speed and performance is limited by my server CPU processing and memory capacity.

My questions seem relatively simple:

1. Do linux servers automatically call-upon both CPU's for high demand processes? I would think, by creating multiple long running threads, both CPU's would be used? Or do I need to go down the route of parallel processing?
2. In terms of a) language features and b) server configurations, are there any other approaches (other than concurrency and parallelism) that can make these download operations perform faster?

Comment: What performance profiling have you done to your application? I very much doubt that your code is limited by CPU performance, unless your two CPU's are extremely feeble. Most likely, the key to performance here is a fast internet connection (and the server where you are downloading from being responsive and having a fast connection!)

Comment: How much is your internet bandwidth? The basis profile standard should be the formula: "All downloaded files size" / "Download time" = "Your internet bandwidth". If "All downloaded files size" / "Download time" is less than bandwidth, then your solution should be optimized, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)